# Windows XP - Setting External Monitor as Primary

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, display, external-display

I'm having problems using two monitors. I can't set my external monitor as the primary, and extended my desktop to the one on the laptop. I does work if I DON'T extended my desktop to the laptops screen, but I would really like that.

I'm using a Lenovo 3000 N200 with a nVidia GeForce Go 7300, on windows XP prof sp3.

I have tried all the solutions I could find online. Like this one:
http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-how-to-change-the-primary-monitor-on-a-laptop/

but doing that simply does not work for me. :(

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you using the most recent version of Presentation Director? Most of these options are best-controlled through it...

Option #2:

> enter bios on boot, F1 key, under Advanced tab, Power On Display,
>   make sure Auto Selected is chosen.
>   Reboot, then verify the settings in Windows are as you want them.
>   Blatantly copied from [Another Poor Soul's Lamentations](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-3000-and-Value-line/Can-I-use-an-external-monitor-as-my-primary-monitor-in-Windows/m-p/241706)

Comment: The solution was to update the nvidia driver, and to set 'Power On Display' to 'Auto Selected' (in BIOS)!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [UltraMon](http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/) which has a 30-day demo period. It supports AFAIK as many monitors as you can plug-in and has a number of options such as configuring which monitor is your primary. I just tested it with my desktop with 2 monitors and it moved the Taskbar and desktop icons to the other monitor.

[image]